# How to associate multiple entities in a many-to-many relationship for Hibernate Search

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-search

Suppose I'm building a grocery store app. I have several types, some of which are related and some which are not, e.g., `Produce`, `Fruit`, `Apple`, `Vegetable`, `Asparagus`, `Meat`, `Chicken`, etc.

All of these types are associated with a collection of `Tag`s in a M:N relationship. Each entity listed above can have multiple `Tag`s, and each `Tag` can be associated with many entities, of various types.

How would I best describe this relationship? Should each type hierarchy have a corresponding `Tag` hierarchy? Using one common `Tag` type works with plain vanilla JPA/Hibernate, but when introducing Hibernate Search, it wants both sides of the relationship described (e.g., using `@ManyToMany(mappedBy = ...)`). How could I accomplish this?

====================== EXAMPLE ========================

Fruit:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Fruit {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @FullTextSearch
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany
  @IndexedEmbedded
  private Collection<Tag> tags;

}
```

Chicken:

```
@Data
@Entity 
@Indexed
public class Chicken {
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @FullTextSearch
  private String brand;

  @ManyToMany
  @IndexedEmbedded
  private Collection<Tag> tags;

}
```

Tag:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Tag {
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @FullTextSearch
  private String name;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate Search needs to have an inverse mapping on the `Tag` side to be able to automatically reindex any of `Produce`, `Fruit`, `Apple`, `Vegetable`, `Asparagus`, `Meat`, `Chicken` etc. whenever a corresponding `Tag` is changed and it would affect the index.

To do so you'd need to modify your `Tag` entity to something like:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Tag {
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @FullTextSearch
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
  private List<Fruit> fruits;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
  private List<Chicken> chickens;

  // and so on ...
}
```

If your tags do not change their names after they've been saved, which would mean that you wouldn't have any changes to tags that would affect fruit/chicken/.../apple indexes you can mark your tag collections with `@IndexingDependency(reindexOnUpdate = ReindexOnUpdate.SHALLOW)`. This will result in fruit/chicken/.../apple indexes being not updated whenever a tag assigned to any of the entities in those indexes is changed.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Fruit {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @FullTextSearch
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany
  @IndexedEmbedded
  @IndexingDependency(reindexOnUpdate = ReindexOnUpdate.SHALLOW)
  private Collection<Tag> tags;

}
```

In that case you do *not* need to modify your `Tag` entity, which doesn't need to model the inverse side of associations:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Tag {
  
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @FullTextSearch
  private String name;

  // No inverse side of associations!

}
```

Please refer to [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-reindexing-reindexonupdate-shallow) in the documentation for a more detailed explanation on shallow indexing.

Comment: Brilliant! That was it. `Tag`s are immutable in my  system, so I went with the second option. Thank you very much!